# Angular starts random ports even using the same config

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an Angular app based on ASP.NET Core, but sometimes after restarting the app using `dotnet watch run` command, it starts using different port, but my launching ports are defined as before in launchSetting.json file:

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
```

I also kill the process that use these ports and restart the app, but it uses a random port. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This problem may also be caused from using https in the url parameters. Change  the url parameters to http and try again before applying other methods. Chrome might be attempting to connect to HTTPs, but you don't have the IIS Express settings to enable HTTPs.

If you want to do this the VS Code way, as long as you use F5 (or the Run > "Start Debugging" command), it's as simple as changing the launch.json file to this:

```
...
"env": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5001"
},
...
```

Otherwise, if you use the IIS Express profile, edit your launchSettings.json file to specify the port:

```
"iisSettings": {
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
  }
},
"profiles" : { ... }
```

For more information related to ASP.NET Core launchSettings.json file:
https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/asp-net-core-launchsettings-json-file/